# DAX / Power Pivot - Count occurrence substring within string of another table without relation

Tags: dax, powerpivot

Dears, i'm stuck in a difficult yet simple task.
I need to count the number of occurence of speficic substrings within a string in a column that as no relation.

Let me give you an example with Emojis :
Table 1:

| People | Message |
| --- | --- |
| John | You got it |
| Paul | So Beautifull |
| John |  |
| Paul | Good luck |

Table 2 :

| Subgroup | Emoticones |
| --- | --- |
| face-smiling |  |
| face-smiling |  |
| face-smiling |  |
| face-smiling |  |
| face-affection |  |
| face-affection |  |

In a pivot, i would like to be able to do this kind of thing with Puivot :

| Subgroup | Total emoji |
| --- | --- |
| face-smiling | 2 |
| face-affection | 4 |

| Person | face-smiling | face-affection |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2 | 0 |
| Paul | 0 | 4 |

Answer (score 1):

I would create a calculated table using `GENERATE()` to iterate over each Emoticone

Then use `ADDCOLUMNS()` to iterate over each Messages, and add the count of the current Emoticone in the current Message.

To count the number of occurrences of an icon in a Message, compute the difference of lengths between Message and Message with removed icons (an icon counts for 2 characters)

And finally `FILTER()` out pairs without match:

```
EmotiCounts = 
VAR cj = GENERATE(Emoticones,
    VAR icon = Emoticones[Emoticones]
    RETURN 
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            Messages, 
            "Counts",
            (
                LEN(Messages[Message])-
                LEN( 
                    SUBSTITUTE( 
                        Messages[Message],
                        icon,
                        ""))
            )/2
        )
    )
 RETURN 
     FILTER( cj, [Counts] > 0 )
```

That table contains both People and Subgroup needed for your visuals.